# How to use Javascript constraint validation api for cross-field checks

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this HTML5/CSS3 form

[image]

When the user clicks the "submit" button I want to check that if the phone-type is "Other" that the description is not blank/empty.

in [pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode):

```
on_submit_do {
  if phone_type == "Other" && trimmed(description) == "" then
    alert_at_component("enter description of other phone type", description)
  else
    continue_as_normal_and_transmit_form_data_to_server
  end_if
}
```

How can I do this **using the [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)**?

---

(See [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57594834/revisions) for code I have tried and original question in full)

Comment: implement your custom validation messages (`HTML`, `CSS` and `JS`).

Comment: @ths, I'm not sure what you mean. I don't want to implement a custom validation message using `window.Alert()` etc, I want to use the Constraint Validation API for visual consistency. See addendum to question

Answer (score 1):

The [constraint validation API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) is generally useful and becomes a must with larger applications where actual constraint *validation* is involved.

I don't however see you doing any *validation* with your use case and question in particular. Nor can the API alone help you solve this. The relationship between your select control and the text area that you are describing, and the resulting behavior, *cannot* be defined though the API alone.

You can solve your problem by reacting to form controls firing `change` events, and switching the `required` attribute on the text area when an option selected in your `select` control (rendered as a drop-down list in your image) is selected. This seems to me like the straightforward approach with your requirements.

You do not need to have your code invoke any alerts or verify whether the form is filled out -- a compliant user agent will issue a warning when attempting to submit a form where a required control is missing a value and will refuse to submit the [incomplete] form. It will even point the user at the control (text area in your case) and alert the user with a message. The message and other aspects of form validation *can* be customized using the the constraint validation API. But the fundamental behavior can and according to my experience, *must* be scripted imperatively.

Consider the following markup with inline (for the sake of the example) script (I've left out things like labels, layout styling and even the submit button, all of these are irrelevant to the demonstration):

```
<form>
    <input name="phone" type="tel"><!-- not sure this is a mandatory input, leaving the "required" attribute out of it, for tersity -->
    <select name="phone_type"><!-- not sure this is a mandatory input, leaving the "required" attribute out of it, for tersity -->
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="desc"></textarea>
    <script>
        (function(form) {
            function update_desc_required() {
                form.elements.desc.required = (form.elements.phone_type.value == "other");
            }
            form.addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
                if(ev.target == form.elements.phone_type) {
                    update_desc_required();
                }
            });
            update_desc_required(); /// You can't assume any particular option is selected
        })(document.currentScript.parentElement);
    </script>
</form>
```

This should be sufficient, but I am not sure about overall design of your form and how usable it is or what you're trying to accomplish. In any case, the `"phone"` type of input should be sufficient to let user enter phone number of their choice.